# How to join two query result and add result in new row if not match in mysql

Tags: mysql

**I have two query result:**

***one produce:***

### **Date**                |      **amount**

22-07-2016            |      105.00

25-07-2016            |      205.00

28-07-2016            |      305.00

30-07-2016            |      30.00

***another produce:***

### **Date**                |      **amount**

15-07-2016            |      55.00

18-07-2016            |      95.00

22-07-2016            |      100.00

25-07-2016            |      200.00

28-07-2016            |      205.00

***i want to add two query like this:***

### **Date**                |      **amount**

22-07-2016            |      205.00

25-07-2016            |      405.00

28-07-2016            |      510.00

30-07-2016            |      30.00

15-07-2016            |      55.00

18-07-2016            |      95.00

what is the query of this result, that return all result if match add amount, if not leave as it is...

Comment: If the 2 queries are from the same table then a sum of amount grouped by date should do. If the 2 queries are using 2 separate tables then a union sub-query with a sum of amount grouped by date should do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`, then `sum` the amount `group by` `date`, try this:

```
select `date`, sum(amount) as amount
from (
    {your query1}
    union all
    {your query2}
) t
group by `date`
```